# Alternative content for facebook share

Tags: php, facebook, http-referer

I'm trying to prepare alternative contet for facebook sharing.
Site is based on flash player (flash is required to enter site) so facebook share shows only:

*'To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version 10.0.0 or greater is installed.'*

Is there any possibility to heck if request is send from facebook and display alternative text / thumb image?

I was trying to play with $_SERVER - without result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [quora](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-user-agent-string-for-the-Facebook-like-share-crawler) the user agent contains the word `facebook` in it suprise suprise so you could just do...

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'facebook') !== false) {
  // show html for facebook
}
else {
  // show flash
}
```